# Create a list of possible drawn numbers to 'visit' up to a sum using numbers from a list

Tags: python, combinations, enumeration

I have a list of numbers for example:

```
lst = [2,7]
```

I want all the possible combinations that can be visited up to a certain number n, for examle

```
n=10
```

So this list would be:

```
[2,4,6,7,8,9,10]

(2 if 2 is drawn, 4 if 2 is drawn twice, 6 if 2 is drawn 3 times,
7 if 7 is drawn, 9 if 7 and 2 are drawn and 10 if 5 times 2 is drawn)
```

I tried several ways, but I keep finding it a really difficult problem. Is there anyone who knows if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: Clue 1: is it possible to solve this with recursion? Clue 2 : all numbers in the list larger than n can be removed (assuming all numbers are positive)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use recursion.

Here is some rough code:

```
def find_possible_sums(numbers, possible, max, current):
    for(number in numbers)
        sum = current + number
        if(sum <= max)
            if(sum not in possible)
                possible.append(sum)
            find_possible_sums(numbers, possible, max, sum)
```

Where numbers = lst, possible is all your possible numbers (empty at first), max is n, and sum is a running total (0 at first).

There are many further optimizations you can make to the solution above if you are concerned about run time.

Comment: Change sum and max for other names because they are reserved. Add colons. Other than that, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is the combinations_with_replacement generator from itertools: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

It will generate all combinations of k elements with repetitions. You will have to call it for each possible value of k - in your case from 1 to n(inclusive). After that you will have to sum the values in each combination.

Example:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, imap, islice
lst = [2,7]
n = 10
combinations = (combinations_with_replacement(lst, k) for k in xrange(1, n + 1))
all_combinations = chain(combinations) 
first_5 = islice(imap(sum, all_combinations), 0, 5)  # Grap the first five.
```

I am using generators because the list of possible combinations grows pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive solution for Python 3:

```
from itertools import chain, takewhile, combinations_with_replacement, count

lst = [2, 7]
l = sorted(lst)
n = 10

set(
    chain.from_iterable(
        takewhile(
            lambda x: x != (),
            map(tuple,
                (takewhile(
                    lambda x: x <= n,
                    map(
                        lambda x: sum(x),
                        combinations_with_replacement(l, p))
                ) for p in count(1)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

> {2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}